# Getting past E518: Unknown option: vsvim_useeditordefaults

Tags: vsvim

I added the vsvim_useeditordefaults option to my _vimrc on Windows 7 which works great in Visual Studio.  But when I try to open up gVim I get the following error:

E518: Unknown option: vsvim_useeditordefaults

Is there anyway to set up an if statement that checks for vsvim in my vimrc so that the option only applies when VsVim loads the vimrc?

Comment: Have you considered using a _vsvimrc file for VsVim?  VsVim will prefer this over a _vimrc and vim will never look at it

Comment: @JaredPar Can you answer the question with your comment so I can close this out as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JaredPar answered the question in the comments:

> Have you considered using a _vsvimrc file for VsVim? VsVim will prefer
>   this over a _vimrc and vim will never look at it